# Drag link and drop to iframe

Tags: javascript, html

how do i drag/pass the link of the image and drop/open in the `iframe` tag ?
Im a beginner , Thanks in advance.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData(URL, ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData(URL);
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<iframe id="left" src="link" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="a"></iframe>
       
    
<div>
  <a href="x" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <img src="source\home.png" id="b">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: iframes are special in that they contain another view (the wrapping page being the first view). You can think of them as showing another tab or window but inset in the containing page. Because of this, the content of the iframe would have to be the thing handling the drop. (Adding debug code shows that the wrapping page doesn't receive any drag-and-drop-related events while dragging over the iframe.) Alternatively, you could temporarily create an overlay, covering the iframe, while the drag is ongoing and use that as your drop target.